# Droid x on Liberty 3 v 2: How can I restore contacts with titanium backup after flashing?

Tags: contacts, custom-roms, backup, restore, titanium-backup

I just rooted my droid X and installed liberty 3v2. Awesome experience so far.

Before I flashed, I backed up most of my apps + system data with titanium backup. What app / data do I need restore from titanium backup in order to get my contacts back?

Answer (score 1):

If your device is linked to a Google Account, merely syncing will restore your contacts and calendar.

Otherwise, in TiB - look for Contacts / Contacts Storage in the backup/restore tab.